# Need help to format a python dictionary string

Tags: string, python-2.7, dictionary

I am unable to convert a file that I downloaded to a dictionary object so that I can access each element. I think the quotations are missing for the keys which prevent me from using json_loads() etc. Could you please help me with some solution. I have given the results of the download below. I need to format it.

```
{
    success: true,
    results: 2,
    rows: [{
        Symbol: "LITL",
        CompanyName: "LancoInfratechLimited",
        ISIN: "INE785C01048",
        Ind: "-",
        Purpose: "Results",
        BoardMeetingDate: "26-Sep-2017",
        DisplayDate: "19-Sep-2017",
        seqId: "102121067",
        Details: "toconsiderandapprovetheUn-AuditedFinancialResultsoftheCompanyonstandalonebasisfortheQuarterendedJune30,2017."
    }, {
        Symbol: "PETRONENGG",
        CompanyName: "PetronEngineeringConstructionLimited",
        ISIN: "INE742A01019",
        Ind: "-",
        Purpose: "Results",
        BoardMeetingDate: "28-Sep-2017",
        DisplayDate: "21-Sep-2017",
        seqId: "102128225",
        Details: "Toconsiderandapprove,interalia,theUnauditedFinancialResultsoftheCompanyforthequarterendedonJune30,2017."
    }]
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the generation of this data? Can you ensure it is generated as valid JSON instead?

Comment: If you're trying to parse that into JSON, you'll need to wrap the property names in quotations, e.g. "Symbol":"LITL"

Comment: It looks like you're hitting some API and that's what is returned, though. If that is the case you made need to parse and reformat that string before it can be parsed into JSON.

Comment: I do not have control over the data. I am getting this from a URL. Is there a way we can download the json data with the url

Comment: Yes. How do i selectively format to have the property names in quotations now

Comment: @JerryPonnoth, sometimes APIs provide an option to specify response type, i.e. text, json, maybe check if the API provides option to specify response type. Also, here's a thread that mentions a function to convert data to json: [comp.lang.python ›
Constructing JSON data structures from non-string key python dictionaries](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/5O2YybR25Oo/I9TzZ4OcrkwJ)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it if you have a string of the dict. It is a little hacky but should work well.

```
import json
import re

regex_string = '(\w{1,}(?=:))'
regex = re.compile(regex_string, re.MULTILINE)
string = open('test_string', 'r').read() # I had the string in a file, but how
# just put the value here based on how you already had it stored.
string = regex.sub(r'"\1"', string)
python_object = json.loads(string)
# Now you can access the python_object just like any normal python dict.
print python_object["results"]
```

Here is the dict after it has been put through the regex. Now you can read it in with json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "results": 2,
    "rows": [{
        "Symbol": "LITL",
        "CompanyName": "LancoInfratechLimited",
        "ISIN": "INE785C01048",
        "Ind": "-",
        "Purpose": "Results",
        "BoardMeetingDate": "26-Sep-2017",
        "DisplayDate": "19-Sep-2017",
        "seqId": "102121067",
        "Details": "toconsiderandapprovetheUn-AuditedFinancialResultsoftheCompanyonstandalonebasisfortheQuarterendedJune30,2017."
    }, {
        "Symbol": "PETRONENGG",
        "CompanyName": "PetronEngineeringConstructionLimited",
        "ISIN": "INE742A01019",
        "Ind": "-",
        "Purpose": "Results",
        "BoardMeetingDate": "28-Sep-2017",
        "DisplayDate": "21-Sep-2017",
        "seqId": "102128225",
        "Details": "Toconsiderandapprove,interalia,theUnauditedFinancialResultsoftheCompanyforthequarterendedonJune30,2017."
    }]
}
```